# Django: Loop / iterate nested list with multiple sublevels

Tags: django, loops, django-views, nested

Here are my snippets:

models.py

```
    class Item(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50, unique=True)
        toplevel = models.BooleanField('Top level item', default=False)
        order = models.IntegerField('Order number', blank=True, null=True) #only if top level is true, determines the top level order

            
    class Hierarchy(models.Model):
        mainitem = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mainitem')
        subitem = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subitem')
        order = models.IntegerField('Order number', default=0) #determines the order of the subitems under the mainitem
```

views.py

```
    def items_view(request, *args, **kwargs):

        items = Item.objects.all()
        toplevelitems = Item.objects.filter(toplevel=True)
        sublevelitems = Item.objects.filter(toplevel=False)

        context = {
            'items':items,
            'toplevelitems':toplevelitems,
            'sublevelitems':sublevelitems,
        }
        return render(request, "itemlist.html", context)
```

itemlist.html

```
    {% if items %}
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                {% for toplevelitem in toplevelitems %}
                <li class="list-group-item">{{ toplevelitem.order }} {{ toplevelitem.name }}</li>
                {% for sublevelitem in sublevelitems %}
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item">{{ sublevelitem.name }}</li>
                </ul>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %} 
            </ul>  
    {% else %}
        <p>No created items</p>
    {% endif %}
```

So what I am trying to built with these is a hierarchy of items that will be itereted for the client in a nested list. What I cannot figure out is how to loop through all the levels of the hierarchy and place them under the right upper level. Here is what I am going for:

```
    Item 1 (top level item)
        Item 1.1 (sub level item)
            Item 1.1.1 (sub sub level item)
                Item 1.1.1.1 (sub sub level item)
                ...
                    item 1.....n (n sub level item) 
                    
        Item 1.2 (sub level item)
            Item 1.2.1 (sub sub level item)
                Item 1.2.1.1 (sub sub level item)
                ...
                    item 1.....n (n sub level item) 

    Item 2 (top level item)
        Item 2.1 (sub level item)
            Item 2.1.1 (sub sub level item)
                Item 2.1.1.1 (sub sub level item)

    and so on...
```

Problem with this is the nested list can contionue up to anything and I don't know how to loop it to the last bit.

I know that the loop in html isn't doing anything like this, it only list all the subitems not considering where it belongs in the hierarchy. What would I need to change, probably in my queries and html to do something like I want?

Comment: Don't 100% get what you want to achieve/what the data looks like -- but seems you should either re-think how the data is stored (improving model logic) or create a dedicated subset as nested dict in the view to loop in the template

Comment: Just on top of my head I would say that the subset as nested dict would be something to try in this case. Here is an example created in sheets just to give better view on the dataset and what type of hierarchy I am trying to accomplish: https://i.postimg.cc/5yYynC4k/hierarchy.png